# Need If statement help and text displaying on screen

Tags: android

I ran my code and in eclipse in the log it is showing under text the output as what my else statement is set to. I do not see this text on the screen.
I am trying to compare a number to a number in my if statement.
I have stated PleaseEnter as android:inputType="number" in the layout. I have included some of the ways that I have tried to change my if statement to compare the values.
I need help with
1. Having if statement validated to show what it needs to and
2. Have the output show on the screen.

```
try 
    PleaseEnter=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.PleaseEnter);
{   
    if ("1".equals(PleaseEnter)) 
    //(PleaseEnter.getText().equals("1"))
    //(PleaseEnter.equals("1")) 
    {
    //   tv.setText("This is the display 1");
        System.out.println("This is 1");
    } 
    else if  (PleaseEnter.equals("2")) 
        System.out.println("This 2");
    else if  (PleaseEnter.equals("3")) 
        System.out.println("This 3");
    else
        System.out.println("That number is not recognized.");
}}
catch (Exception ex)
```

Comment: You don't need the try/catch block in this case, and the syntax is wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if ("1".equals(PleaseEnter.getText().toString().trim())) {
//your stuffs
} else .....
```

Comment: Thanks to both, but now I need help to display the text on the screen.

Comment: @pra then use android widget TextView.it's package is import android.widget.TextView;

Answer (score 0):

PleaseEnter is an EditText, but you are testing to see if it equals a String.  You should be comparing against `PleaseEnter.getText()`;

An even better approach is to first convert the contents of your text field to a number, like:

```
    Integer entered =  new Integer(PleaseEnter.getText());
    if (entered == 1){
    //do stuff
    }
    else if (entered == 2){
    //etc...
   }
```